# How to set UiScrollView Frame on click of UIButton in Iphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

I have UIScrollView on which I am using 2 UIButtons. UIScrollView initial frame is (0,0,768,1024). I want when I click on first button  the UIScrollView y-cordinate position will be 500, means it will scrolldown 500 positions below to its actual position.

And when I click second Button which Will show on UIScrollView, Position Y-cordinate of UIScrollView y=535, then UIScrollView Move up to Position y= 0 again.

First button click UIScrollView  y = 500
Second button click UIScrollView y = 0

Any hints from experts would be very welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may solve ur pbm

```
-(IBAction) clickfirstbutton 
{
   [scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 500)) animated:TRUE];
}

-(IBAction) clicksecondbutton
{
   [scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:TRUE];
}
```

If u don't want animations use

```
[scrollview setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, 0) animated:FALSE];
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you do not want to change the **`frame`** of the scroll view (this would just displace the whole view), but the **`contentOffset`**. This can be animated, too.

```
CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;
offset.y += 500;
[scrollView setContentOffset:offset animated:YES];
```